# How to minimize an expression to show the norm

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, inequality

I'm quite surprised I can't solve this problem. Given the following function :

$\forall\left(x,y\right)\in\mathbb{R}^{2},\quad f(x,y)=x^{4}+y^{4}-2(x-y)^{2}$

show that $\forall\left(x,y\right)\in\mathbb{R}^{2} \quad f(x,y)\geq{\frac{1}{2}}(x^{2}+y^{2})^{2}-4(x^{2}+y^{2})$

I show that $2(x-y)^{2} \leq 4(x^{2}+y^{2})$

Then I want to show that $x^{4}+y^{4} \geq  \frac{1}{2}(x^{2}+y^{2})^{2}$

But it's here that I'm struggling, I can only show that $x^{4}+y^{4} \geq 2x^{2}y^{2}$

And I can't go further. I know that you can solve the exercice the other way around, by maximizing $\frac{1}{2}(x^{2}+y^{2})^{2}$, but I want to understand, how you can do it without knowing the result, in the case I have to show in the future that a function is infinite.

Thanks everyone

Comment: I mean, how do I get the intuition that : 
$x^{4}+y^{4} \geq \frac{1}{2}(x^{4}+y^{4}) + x^{2}y^{2}$

Is there any tips like that, that I should know in the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- *"I want to show that $x^4+y^4\ge\frac12(x^2+y^2)^2$ but I can only show that $x^4+y^4\ge2x^2y^2$"*
  Well, you're done!
  $$\begin{align}x^4+y^4\ge\frac12(x^2+y^2)^2&\iff2(x^4+y^4)\ge x^4+2x^2y^2+y^4\\
  &\iff x^4+y^4\ge2x^2y^2.
  \end{align}$$
- *"I want to understand, how you can do it without knowing the result, in the case I have to show in the future that a function is infinite."* and later in comment : *" you might also want to minizime the expression of a function by an expression only depending of the norm of (x,y)."*
  I would use polar coordinates, and minimize independently the two terms of this sum:
  $$\begin{align}f(x,y)&=r^4\left(1-\frac{\sin^2(2\theta)}2\right)+2r^2(\sin(2\theta)-1)\\&\ge r^4\left(1-\frac12\right)+2r^2(-1-1)\\
  &=\frac{r^4}2-4r^2.
  \end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you, but as I wrote it in my question, I know it’s easy to show it when you’ve got the answer by successive equivalences. But how do you find it without?

Comment: @UItraviolet I didn't really understand your problem?

Comment: Here in my exercise, the result to prove was shown. But in reality, you might also want to minizime the expression of a function by an expression only depending of the norm of (x,y). But then how do you know the right way to minimize your expression ?

Comment: Wow thank you ! I’ve never seen that before, is there any other tricks of the sort I should know?

Comment: Instead of minimizing independently the two terms, you could minimize (for fixed $r>0$) the function $g(s):=r^4(1-s^2/2)+2r^2(s-1)$ for $s\in[-1,1]$, but here it would give the same result: the minimum is $g(-1)$. And if you didn't notice that everything was expressible in terms of $\sin(2\theta)$, you could minimize the (slightly more complicated) function(s) of $\theta$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $$f(x,y)-\frac{(x^2+y^2)^2}{2}+4(x^2+y^2)=x^4+y^4-2(x-y)^2-\frac{(x^2+y^2)^2}{2}+4(x^2+y^2)$$

and expanding these expression show that $f(x,y)-\frac{(x^2+y^2)^2}{2}+4(x^2+y^2) \geq0$

Comment: Yeah, I know it’s that easy when you know by what quantity you want to minimize the function. But when you don’t how do you get this idea?